# GetElementByIdのSetAttributeで文字入力が上手くいかない場合の解決策はありますか？

Tags: javascript, c#, html

https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/buy

ID要素のテキストボックスに文字を入力するだけなのですが

```
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recipient").SetAttribute("value","test@mail");
```

上記コードだと表面上は入力は出来てもvalueに文字が反映されません。
（また、テキストボックスをクリックすると入力された文字も消えます）

追記：問題の現象をGIF化しました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

1度目、textboxへ入力、disable属性を無効化後ボタンクリック⇒入力前に戻る

```
  //textboxへ入力
  dynamic document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
  document.getElementById("recipient").value = "test@mail";
  //disable属性無効化
  dynamic document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
  document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").disabled = false;
```

２度目、質問の通り、textboxへ上記コードで入力後textboxをクリックしてみると消えることが確認できます。(valueに反映されてないということかと思います。)

３度目、上記コード内容を手動でやってみると次の画面へ推移することが確認できます。

原因が分かる方はご教授いただけると助かります。
よろしくおねがいいたします。
visual studio express 2015 for desktop (64bit) windows10

Comment: 他の質問スレッドは放置でしょうか？

Comment: いつもご回答いただき感謝しております。
実は、今日も既にいくつかのスレッドを解決済みにさせていただいております。
ご回答いただいた内容を理解したり検証するのに時間がかかっております。
ご容赦いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 回答内容を理解する前に質問を繰り返しても類似質問になるだけですので、まずは先行しているスレッドを理解してからにすることをお勧めします。特に本スレッドは[webbrowserの自動化処理でdisabledを処理するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36748/4236)とほぼ同じです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
類似の質問大変失礼いたしました。
もう少し熟読して理解を深められるようにしていきたいと思います。

Comment: 結局、本件はWebBrowserコントロール操作の一般論の質問でしょうか？ それともpaypal固有の質問でしょうか？ 後者ならpaypalタグも付与すべきですが、その場合はAPIなども検討すべきかと。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
WEBBrowserコントロールの問題かと思っていたのですが、
どうやらpaypal固有の問題だったようです。
>paypalタグも付与すべき
⇒paypalタグというのがよく分からないのですが、
APIの使用検討してみます。

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLInputElement`の`value`プロパティはユーザーの入力によって変化しうるため、初期値である`value`属性の値とは[同期しない仕様](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-49531485)となっています。

Answer (score 1):

属性には[content属性とIDL属性](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#Content_versus_IDL_attributes)とがあり、プロパティと一致しないものもあります。件の`value`属性も`value`プロパティとは別物です。
その上で解決策ですが、[webbrowserの自動化処理でdisabledを処理するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/36778/4236)でも回答しましたが、HTML操作は簡単です。

```
dynamic document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
document.getElementById("recipient").value = "test@mail";
```

で済みます。

---

> テキストボックスをクリックすると入力された文字も消えます

とのことですが、つまり入力そのものは成功していると思われます。その上で、当該Webサイトでは自動操作対策が行われていて、入力内容がリセットされているのではないでしょうか？ 特定サイトに起因する問題ですし、自動操作対策であれば回避した場合には不正アクセスにもなり兼ねません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
確かに入力はできるのですが、valueに反映されていないようです。
（GIFと詳細を質問に追記させていただきました。）

Comment: なるほど。そういう事だったのですね。
勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。